# How to generate certificate or key store for server using annoymous diffie-hellmen algorithm

Tags: tomcat, soap, ssl, wsdl, diffie-hellman

I want to create certificate using Anonymous diffie Hellman algorithms as need to create HTTPS web service with no authentication to perform.
Need help how can i configure certificate for Server and also steps to set up tomcat server.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, *anonymous* DH cipher suites don't require authentication of either parties. Hence, they don't use a certificate at all. You don't need to set a keystore in this case. It doesn't make any sense to create a certificate for anonymous DH.

(The lack of keystore is in fact one of the cause for the "no cipher suites in common" message when you're not using anonymous DH cipher suites, which are sensibly disabled by default.)

If you want to use anonymous DH cipher suites, it's the cipher suites you need to configure (see the names with `anon` in the [list of cipher suites disabled by default](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJSSEProvider)).

Note that they're disabled by default for a good reason: they make the connection vulnerable to MITM attacks. If you want the connection to be secure, you should always at least have the client verify the identity of the server (by configuring a certificate on the server).